# Thermosensor Error - 'Wire' does not name type?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, temperature-sensor

Here is the code I am using:

```
#define D6T_ID 0x0A
#define D6T_CMD 0x4C

int ReadBuffer[35];
float ptat;
float tdata[16];

#include <Wire.h>
void setup() {
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(500);

}

void loop() {

}
  int i;
  Wire.beginTransmission(D6T_ID);
  Wire.write(D6T_CMD);
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.requestFrom(D6T_ID,35);

  for (i=0; i<35; ++i) {
    ReadBuffer[i] = Wire.read();
  }

  ptat = (ReadBuffer[0]+(ReadBuffer[1]*256))*0.1; //Reference Temp

  for (i=0; i<16; ++i) {
    tdata[i] = (ReadBuffer[(i*2+2)]+(ReadBuffer[(i*2+3)]*256))*0.1;
  }

  float tempF;

  if ( ((tdata[0]*9.0/5.0)+32.0)>0 )
  {
    for (i=0; i<16; ++i)
    {
      tempF = (tdata[i]*9.0/5.0)+32.0;
      Serial.print(tempF);
      Serial.print(',');
    }
    Serial.print((ptat*9.0/5.0)+32.0;
    Serial.print(',');
    Serial.println();
  }

    }
  }
```

This is the error I am getting:

exit status 1
'Wire' does not name a type

And it highlights this area of code:

```
Wire.requestFrom(D6T_ID,35);
```

I am completely new to using the arduino and coding so I am not sure if I already have the wire library that this code requires but when I look at the libraries in the Tools menu it is there. Do I need to download another library? If so can someone send me the link? Can someone explain what the error means? This is all foreign to me.

Thank you

Comment: ***** It should say #include <Wire.h>

Comment: Your braces are not right. For example, for the loop function you have an open brace and then a close brace before you code starts.

Answer (score 1):

You've goofed up your braces and none of that code is in `loop()`. Look at the braces in the code and make the appropriate corrections.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error message is that your braces do not properly match, and the code that was meant to be inside `loop()` is not, but instead looks to the compiler like some new global declarations. Fix the syntax errors and your code will compile:

- Remove the brace in line 18 that closes the loop() function prematurely,
- Fix the missing ')' in line 46,
- Remove line 52, an extraneous '}',